# GitHub local repository

Tags: git, github

We don't have much budget yet to buy a private repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/). Is there a local version of [GitHub](https://github.com/)?

Thanks.

Comment: You could consider [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/).

Comment: Does `GitLab` support all programming languages?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  It's to host your Git repositories in a manner very similar to GitHub.  It doesn't care about what language your content is written in.  If you're talking about color syntax highlighting in the file views, it's using Pygments under-the-hood, which supports many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To create a local repository, you can just use git.
- you can also run git on the server, and there are ton of solutions for that. Just google that. It is really easy to setup.

What github adds to git is a very nice UI and social features: it is really easy to cooperate with complete strangers and teams. You can run github on your own server, but that is even more expensive.

There are open source alternatives for github, which you can install on your own server:

- gitlab
- gitorious

Of those gitlab is the easiest to install yourself, but afaik it is not completely straightforward.

Bitbucket offers free private repositories and supports git as well.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is a server for git repositories.
You can create your own repository localy, 
But, if you need github features as issues or network graph, you have to create a free software... or look on https://bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's a local version of github, you'll find it at http://enterprise.github.com since github is closed source this costs of course money.

So if you want inhouse hosting of git repositories I suggest you look at gitolite or gitlab.

There's several git hosting services on the internet, some of them allow you to have private repos for free, bitbucket is the most wellknown one but have a look at the list at:
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting

However, you should consider if you really trust the hosting service you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spend $10, you  can get atlassian stash (10 users) license. 
Initially they can give you eval license for 1 month.

disclaimer: I am not associated with atlassian, but I am a user of atlassian stash and jira.